# json_encode return false when the page contain Arabic data

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, codeigniter

I am using ajax function to fetch data from database and replace a div.The data is fetched and the page is created from the controller, but when I use PHP `json_encode` it return false.

Then I used the below code:

```
    $data=utf8_encode($this->load->view('site' . $_SESSION['language'] . '/property_data', $data, TRUE));

    json_encode($data);
```

I am getting the out put like this after the encoding,

[image]

Here the encoding works fine,but when I use JavaScript decode, it's not working (the Arabic content is not displaying properly).

Comment: Show us the encoded data.

Comment: This question is missing a [mcve], and probably cannot be answered in its current form.

Comment: Check [json_last_error_msg](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error-msg.php) to see what’s failing

Answer (score 1):

First you need set the charset of your DB with utf-8, if you are using mysql use :

```
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
```

And then in your json_encode use:

```
json_encode($result, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
```

Hope it helps

Comment: I got the result from DB correctly and then I passed the data to the page and assigned that page to a variable, after that I apply json encoding,at that time it return false.How to solve it.